# JSON and Radio Button input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm trying to make a webpage that produces a different card depending on what you choose.

Here are some of my radio buttons and a normal button:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="Ace" value="1" id="rank"> Ace
  <input type="radio" name="2" value="2" id="rank"> 2
  <input type="radio" name="3" value="3" id="rank"> 3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="4" value="4" id="rank"> 4

  <button id="btn1">Deal the Card</button>
```

Here is the js code I'm using:

```
 var getRank = function(x){
var rank = 
'{"1": "Ace", "2": "2", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5", "6": "6", "7": "7", "8": "8", "9": "9", "10": "10",\
  "11": "Jack", "12": "Queen", "13": "King"}'
var rank = JSON.parse(rank)

return rank[x]
}

 var dealCard = function(){
     var input = (document.querySelector("#rank").value)
     var input2 = (document.querySelector("#suit").value)

     if (input === rank[i])
        return getRank(input)

 var main = function() {

console.log(this.id);

if (this.id == "btn1")
{   
    dealCard()
}

  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {

//select the buttons
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

//register the same handler for each button
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", main);
}

 });
```

So I'm trying to have the page set up to when I click the normal button, it displays what kind of card I have based on what radio button is selected. So if I select the "Ace" radio button, I want it to take that radio button and run it through the getRank function, and then display the results after I select the Deal Card button. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Cause right now nothing happens when i click the deal button.

Comment: So you are not getting the console log output? Also seems to be a scoping issue. Where does `rank[i]` come from in the dealCard function. Look at your console to see what is going on.

Comment: `if (input === rank[i])` using `rank` before it gets defined

Comment: So i switched it to

if (input === getRank(x))

And when running it on the console it shows that the first input variable is given a value, either 1, 2, 3, etc., but then says that x is defined. Where and how would I define that? If not x, what should input be equal to for the function to compare the input to the getRank function?

Answer (score 2):

I think the main cause is not missing something, it is the wrong usage of **radio** element. That is, you have to name them by a same **name** attribute like *rank* and whenever **DON NOT** give any two or above elemets a same **id** attribute. By the way, the better way of comparison of 2 things is using **index**.

In conclusion, there were some changes I did as followings:

1. Removed **id** attribute.
2. Replaced all **name** attributes of **radio**s as *rank*.
3. Set the argument of **querySelector** as *"input[name=rank]:checked"*.
4. Gave default value for input value when nothing is selected.
5. Passed deal card no by *1* means the index of *ACE*. You can change it whatever you want.

Check it and tell me whether it works for you or not.

```js
var rank = '{"1": "Ace", "2": "2", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5", "6": "6", "7": "7", "8": "8", "9": "9", "10": "10", "11": "Jack", "12": "Queen", "13": "King"}';
rank = JSON.parse(rank);

var getRank = function(x) {
  return rank[x];
}

var dealCard = function(i) {
  var input = document.querySelector("input[name=rank]:checked");
  input = input == null ? '1' : input.value;
  //var input2 = document.querySelector("#rank-2").value;

  if (input == i)
    return getRank(input)
}

var main = function() {

  if (this.id == "btn1") {   
    console.log(dealCard("1")); // Change parameter as index.
  }

}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  //select the buttons
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

  //register the same handler for each button
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", main);
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="1"/> Ace
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="2"/> 2
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="3"/> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="4"/> 4

<button id="btn1">Deal the Card</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has compilation issues as you are missing `}` bracket in `dealCard` function and mentioned in comments you are trying to access `rank` even before it is defined.

```
var rank = 
'{"1": "Ace", "2": "2", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5", "6": "6", "7": "7", "8": "8", "9": "9", "10": "10",
  "11": "Jack", "12": "Queen", "13": "King"}';

var getRank = function(x){

   rank = JSON.parse(rank);

   return rank[x];
}

 var dealCard = function(){
     var input = document.querySelector('input[id="rank"]:checked').value;
     //call the getRank with clicked
     return getRank(input);

 } //you had missed this.

 window.addEventListener("load", function() {

     document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
         dealCard();
      });
 });
```

Comment: So i switched it to if (input === getRank(x)) And when running it on the console it shows that the first input variable is given a value, either 1, 2, 3, etc., but then says that x is defined. Where and how would I define that? If not x, what should input be equal to for the function to compare the input to the getRank function?

Comment: tried this and it just says "unexpected token in JSON at position 1"

Comment: also says "object Object"

Comment: @user2951723 try updated answer. I have refactored your code completely.